# Edit the tag output of a text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I'm using the following WYSIWYG editor plugin: [summernote](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote)

When you make the text bold in the editor, it outputs as:

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;">TEXT</span>
```

What I'm trying to do is have it output as a normal bold tag:

```
<b>TEXT</b>
```

However, I can't find the part in the code where it sets the tags so that I can change it.

Here's the source code for the editor: http://pastebin.com/yvg9R4id

Can someone help me find the part in the code where it sets the tags?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have `onchange` property with your editor then , you may use `if($('span').css('font-weight')=='bold'){
$(this).text('<b>'+your_editor_text+'</b>')
}`

Comment: Your WYSIWYG editor plugin defines bold in line `753`      `oStyle['font-bold'] = document.queryCommandState('bold') ? 'bold' : 'normal';`

Comment: BTW, this is the link to the min.js version of the editor: http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/summernote-dist/summernote.min.js

Comment: If I try the online demo provided at http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/ it uses `<strong>` to make text bold – as it should be. Are you using the current version? Did you have modified it before?

Comment: @tas9 No this is not a good question, as it could get answered by the search function of any random editor. Also, what should we do with the minified version? Nobody could read that.